# Can't see External Libraries Folder in my Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio

Even though I have added dependencies in the gradle, I can't find a folder by the name "External Libraries" in my Android Studio Project.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: What makes you think there is supposed to be one?

Comment: Probably because Eclipse shows one (if you add it).